# Having trouble accessing network shares from one particular computer on another particular computer

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

My desktop can connect to my media box.  And my media box can connect to my laptop. But my desktop can not connect to my laptop.  I've configured the network settings and share settings correctly.  What can I do to grant my desktop access to my laptop?  I'm obviously semi-desperate and hitting some sort of Windows bug.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that won't make sense to try unless you actually read about it working for others, is to change the name of your laptop machine.  You can do this by right clicking on `This PC`-> `Properties` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Computer Name (Tab)` -> `Network ID` or `Change`.

Original (buried) source:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-pro-cannot-access-shared-computers/757385af-13fe-472a-911a-172f1c800337

Comment: Note that I had already removed the credentials on the desktop for the laptop -- but to no avail.

Comment: The other thing that I tried in parallel was running the `Network ID` wizard (under PC properties) on the desktop.  I haven't yet restarted the desktop, so I don't think those changes are in effect.  However, I mention it, because there's a small chance that's really what fixed the issue.